# Find a pattern in an array

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have this array:

```
resultArray = ["08:30-10:45", "15:15-17:30"]
```

I would like to write a javascript that reads this array and return true of the timeslots comes between 00:00 - 08:00.I have written below javascript but this seems not working.

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
    var bar = /^00:^01:^02:^03:^04:^05:^06:^07:^08/;
    if (bar.test(resultArray[i])) {
        return true
    }
};
```

I would want to exclude value if it is 08:01 and so on and strictly want to check between 00:00-08:00. Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: `return true` doesn't make sense inside a `for` loop (here). Try `.filter` instead

Comment: Do you want it to return an array of true and false based your regex or to filter the array based on the regex?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
resultArray = resultArray.filter(e => e.test(pattern))
```

Comment: Got this worked. Thank you everyone for the suggestions.